# Compute $E[\min(T_1+T_2, S)]$, where $T_1, T_2$ and $S$ are exponential random variables

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

Let $T_1, T_2$ be exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ and $S$ an exponential random variable with parameter $\mu$. It is assumed also that these are all independent. We are asked to calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}[\min(T_1+T_2, S)]$.

I got the wrong answer by solving it like this:

Consider the given random variables as arrival times of the first arrival in Poisson processes. Then merge the processes of $T_1$ and $T_2$. That process then has parameter $2\lambda$, right? Call that process $M$.

Then merge $M$ with the process of $S$.

Now we must solve the expected value of the random variable

$$X = \text{time before arrival from $S$ or two arrivals from $M$}.$$
I started solving it by conditioning on whether the first arrival is from $M$ or $S$:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{P}(1\text{st arrival is from M})\mathbb{E}[X\space | \space 1\text{st arrival is from M}] + \mathbb{P}(1\text{st arrival is from S})\mathbb{E}[X\space | \space 1\text{st arrival is from S}]$$

$$=\frac{2\lambda}{\mu + 2\lambda}\mathbb{E}[X\space | \space 1\text{st arrival is from M}] + \frac{\mu}{\mu + 2\lambda}\frac{1}{\mu}.$$
Here I'm not sure if this is correct but for calculating $\mathbb{E}[X\space | \space 1\text{st arrival is from M}] $ we have the first arrival given that it comes from $M$ so add the expected for that and start the process anew after the that first arrival and condition similarly on where the second arrival comes from to get

$$\mathbb{E}[X\space | \space 1\text{st arrival is from M}] $$

$$= \frac{1}{2\lambda} + \frac{\mu}{\mu+2\lambda}\frac{1}{\mu} + \frac{2\lambda}{\mu+2\lambda}\frac{1}{2\lambda}.$$

So alltogether I got

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{2\mu+8\lambda}{(\mu+2\lambda)^2}.$$

But like I said this is not correct (simulation doesn't support this and the answer should actually be $\frac{\mu+2\lambda}{(\mu+2\lambda)^2}$. The question and a solution are [from here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-041-probabilistic-systems-analysis-and-applied-probability-fall-2010/assignments/), problem set 7, question 3. I don't understand the solution given there (why is there no $2\lambda$?) and I'd like to know what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: If $X=\min(T_1+T_2,S)$ is the time before arrival from $S$ with intensity $\mu$ or two arrivals from M, then M should have intensity $\lambda$, not $2\lambda$, right? Note that there are much quicker ways to reach $E(X)$ than what you explain but I understand that you are asking about the method you used, not about the best way to solve the exercise.

Comment: I'm trying to solve it with one arrival at a time, not two. One thing about the answer in the link I'm baffled about is that why is the conditional expectation of the wait time, given that the first arrival is from $S$, $1/(\mu+\lambda)$ and not $1/\mu$ if we know that the arrival was from $S$.

Comment: Sorry but I do not know how your comment is addressing mine (actually I suspect it does not).

Comment: The problem is you're thinking of it as the time until two arrivals from the process $T_1+T_2$...this is wrong. It is either two arrivals from the process $T \sim T_1$ and has arrival rate $\lambda$ or a single arrival from the process $T\sim T_1+ T_2$ which has arrival rate $2\lambda$.